# How to configure startup order of stateless services?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to configure startup order when starting up the services.

A Service1 has to be running before Service2 can be started.

Clarification: 
I'm didn't mean micro services when I mentioned Service, I meant stateless services like REST API (Service1) and WebSocket (Service2).

So when then solution is deployed the WebSocket service (Service2) must be up and running before the REST API (Service1)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course you can, because you control when services are created. It's not immediately obvious if you've only ever deployed applications through Visual Studio, because Visual Studio sets you up with *Default Services*. This is what you see in ApplicationManifest.xml when you create an application through Visual Studio:

```
<DefaultServices>
   <Service Name="Stateless1">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="Stateless1Type" InstanceCount="[Stateless1_InstanceCount]">
         <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
   </Service>
   <Service Name="Stateful1">
      <StatefulService ServiceTypeName="Stateful1Type" TargetReplicaSetSize="[Stateful1_TargetReplicaSetSize]" MinReplicaSetSize="[Stateful1_MinReplicaSetSize]">
         <UniformInt64Partition PartitionCount="[Stateful1_PartitionCount]" LowKey="-9223372036854775808" HighKey="9223372036854775807" />
      </StatefulService>
   </Service>
</DefaultServices>
```

This is a nice convenience when you know you always want certain services created a certain way each time you create an application instance. You can define them declaratively here and Service Fabric will create them whenever you create an instance of the application.

But it has some drawbacks. Most notably, in your case, is that you have no control over the order in which the services are created.

It also hides some of the concepts around application and service *types* and application and service *instances*, which again can be convenient until you want to do something more advanced, like in your case.

When you "deploy" an application, there are actually several steps:

1. Create the application package
2. Copy the package up to the cluster
3. Register the application type and version
4. Create an instance of the registered application type and version
5. Create instances of each registered service type in that application

With Default Services, you skip step 5 because Service Fabric does it for you. Without Default Services though, you get to create your service instances yourself, so you can determine what order to do it in. You can do other things like check if a service is ready before creating the next one. All of these actions are available in Service Fabric's C# SDK and PowerShell cmdlets. Here's a quick PowerShell example:

```
Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage -ApplicationPackagePath C:\temp\MyApp -ImageStoreConnectionString fabric:ImageStore -ApplicationPackagePathInImageStore MyApp

Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType MyApp

New-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName fabric:/MyAppInstance -ApplicationTypeName MyApp -ApplicationTypeVersion 1.0

New-ServiceFabricService -ApplicationName fabric:/MyAppInstance -InstanceCount 1 -PartitionSchemeSingleton -ServiceName fabric:/MyAppInstance/MyStatelessService -ServiceTypeName MyStatelessService -Stateless

New-ServiceFabricService -ApplicationName fabric:/MyAppInstance -MinReplicaSetSize 2 -PartitionSchemeSingleton -ServiceName fabric:/MyAppInstance/MyStatefulService -ServiceTypeName MyStatefulServiceType -Stateful -TargetReplicaSetSize 3
```

Of course, this just applies to creating the service instances. When it comes time to upgrading your services, the "upgrade unit" is actually the application, so you can't pick the order in which services within an application get upgraded, at least not in one single upgrade. You can, however, choose *which* services get upgraded during an application upgrade, so if you have the same ordering dependency, you can accomplish that by doing two separate application upgrades.

So you get some level of control. But, it's really best if your services are resilient to missing dependent services, because there will likely be times when a service is unavailable for one reason or another.

Edit:
I showed you a lot of PowerShell but I should mention the C# APIs are also just as powerful. You have the full set of management tools at your disposal in C#. For example, you can have a service that creates and manages other services. In your case, if Service A depends on Service B, then you can have Service A create an instance of Service B before Service A itself does any work, and throughout Service A's life it can keep an eye on Service B. Here's an example of a service that creates other applications and services: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-management-party-cluster/blob/master/src/PartyCluster.ApplicationDeployService/FabricClientApplicationOperator.cs

Comment: This was exactly the answer I was looking for and more! Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help! Can you do me a favor and mark this as "answered" for me?

Answer (score 0):

In service fabric world it's called Service Affinity (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-advanced-placement-rules-affinity/)

Anyway, try to avoid these situations in microservices world.
Good luck.

Comment: This is not exactly the answer I was looking due to my poor question. I'll edit my question to be more precise. Useful link anyway, thanks!